# Empty response however browser downloads video

Tags: python, download, python-requests

I have been trying to download some videos with python code below. When I run the code, it always download an empty file, however if I open the URL in web browser (Chrome) it downloads the file correctly. The response from the code is

Headers:

```
    {'Server': 'nginx', 'Date': 'Sat, 18 May 2019 17:31:02 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/download', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Keep-Alive': 'timeout=20', 
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=video0.mp4', 'Content-Description': 'File Transfer', 
    'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-Clacks-Overhead': 'GNU Terry Pratchett', 'X-HTTPS-Protocol': 'TLSv1.2',
    'X-HTTPS-Cipher': 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384'}
```

The content I'm getting from response:

```
    b''
```

The code I'm trying to download with is

```py
def downloadVideo(filename, url):
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    open(filename, 'wb').write(response.content)
    print ("Downloaded " + filename)
```

Is there any other way how to make this work? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

you should write it in chunks incase it's a big file, try this:

```
def downloadVideo(filename, url):
    with requests.get(url, stream=True) as r:
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=8192): 
                if chunk:
                    f.write(chunk)
    print ("Downloaded " + filename)
```